# How do you find elements of Kotlin coroutineContext?

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin coroutines, an element is defined thus:

```
    interface Element : CoroutineContext
```

If you read tutorials, they give you a list of Elements: Dispatchers.IO, Dispatchers.Main and so on.
But on the page defining this interface you don't find any of its inheritors.
My question is Does Jetbrains want you to read all the pages about coroutines and find the Elements for yourself?

Comment: Why do you need it in the first place? I mean, usually it works like this: you need something -> you search -> you find solution. Looking for all possible elements is like searching for solutions to problems that we don't have yet. If this is just for curiosity and learning then AFAIK there are very few elements recognized by coroutines framework right now: `Job`, `ContinuationInterceptor`,  `CoroutineExceptionHandler`, `NonCancellable`, `CoroutineName` are among the most important ones. Of course, you can create your own elements if you need.

Comment: The IDE has a little green icon in the left gutter next to interfaces. If you click it, it shows a list of all inheritors with  links.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. And I am using android studio arctic fox. When I click on the green icon there appears a list of subclasses, but I cannot find Job, which is obviously an element. What's odd is that the list has all the 4 elements listed above by broot.